Regex to match strings with only one delimiter
I have a specific request to validate an input field to add value with a delimiter occurring only once. researched community but found posts for reading delimiter at least once or multiple occurrences.
I created the regex below but cannot get it to read the delimiter only once.
^.+?\S(?=\|).+?\S+$

Requirements:

Should not have space before and after the delimiter (e.g. abc | xyz - fail) added \S to read whitespaces
The value cannot be empty before and after the delimiter (e.g. |xyz - fail)
The value cannot have multiple delimiters (e.g. abc||xyz or abc|xyz| - fail)


Looks like ^[^|\s]+\|[^|\s]+$.

Use ^[^|]*[^\s|]\|[^\s|][^|]*$ if you want spaces to be disallowed only around the delimiter.

Or, ^[^|]+(?<!\s)\|(?!\s)[^|]+$ or ^(?![^|]*(?:\s\||\|\s))[^|]+\|[^|]+$
